# How can I format a month in mmm format?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format a date in Excel with VBA, the current month to be in *mmm* format. Somehow I am getting the previous month, instead of the current month. I have checked and my computer month is Feb, but I am getting Jan, instead.

This is my code:

```
Cells(1, 2) = Format(month(Date), "mmm")
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just format the existing date directly, ie

```
Cells(1, 2) = Format(Date, "mmm")
```

Answer (score 13):

You are formating the date **1/1/1900**

Let me explain:

- `Date` is worth `21/02/2012`
- `Month(Date)` is worth `1`
- `Format` will consider this as a date so Month(Date) will be `1/1/1900`
- So `Format(month(Date), "mmm")` will return `Jan` as the month of `1/1/1900`

To [teach you fishing](http://www.amatecon.com/fish.html), when you face this kind of issue, you can try to find the value of each statement :

- `Debug.Print (Date)` returns `21/02/2012` so this part is ok
- `Debug.Print (Format(Month(Date), "mmm"))` returns `jan` so this is not a displaying cell issue

Comment: +1 for explaining while it failed. I continued with my post once I was notified by yours as mine gave a solution.

Comment: @brettdj: very true... I focused on the issue instead of the solution :)